# Writing php in Jquery Json object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a statement within my `php-json-jquery` object code that looks like so:

```
 echo "{'year':'".$tree."'}";
```

i want to make the $tree variable a link so that a user can be able to click on it!
I have tried giving the variable an anchor `[<a href></a>]` tag but it hasnt worked.

Comment: Where's the code that didn't work?

Comment: echo "{'year':'<a href="#">".$tree."</a>'}";

Comment: I'm confused about your question. You want to make a json in php then pass it on jquery an object?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to echo json then you must do it with `json_encode` method available in php:

```
<?php
    $anchor = "<a href='#'>".$tree."</a>";
    $arr = array('year' => $anchor);

    echo json_encode($arr); // prints {"year":"<a href='#'>date</a>"}
?>
```

Comment: yeah..okay! but that piece of code doesnot run in javascript -- how can i make that php code work in jquery??

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't run in javascript? have you tried it with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Yes @Jai, i wanna run that piece of code from within a Jquery code? but Javascript doesn't understand the <?php tags or php code!